# Ionic / Angular date input set programatically using moment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I'm trying to set the value of a "date" input but im getting this error message :

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `03/27/2012` to be a date
```

I was under the impression that the correct format was MM/DD/YYYY? ive also tried DD/MM/YYYY.

I'm using moment.js to format then setting the value of the textbox.

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Date Entered :</span>
            <input type="date" placeholder="Date Entered" value="" ng-model="entered">
          </label>
```

controller :

```
$scope.entered = moment($scope.entered).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

Comment: `... = new Date( moment($scope.entered).format("YYYY-MM -DD"));` ? Also why are you mutating the type on `$scope.entered` it is coming in as `Date` but `moment.format` changes is to `String` ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called angular-moment, where you can use a variety of filters.

Check it out: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
dateobj = $scope.entered

    var tempobj = {

        year: dateobj.getFullYear(),
        month: dateobj.getMonth(),
        day: dateobj.getDate()

    }

  var momentobj = moment(tempobj).format('format it the way you want to');
```